# CSS: Making Image Fill Whole Screen

Tags: html, css

How to make an image fill the whole screen (100% x 100%) ?

I am using Flex-Boxes, 100% height on the html-tag, but somehow it doesn't work.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

.background-image {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="background-image">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1 class="title">site-title</h1>
    <h2 class="description">site-description</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `height: 100%;` to the `.background-image` class, too, since by default it will only be as tall as the children inside it.

```css
html, body {height:100%;}

.background-image {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="background-image">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1 class="title">site-title</h1>
    <h2 class="description">site-description</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: well, here it works, but in my code on my computer it doesn't... `height: 100%;` on `background-image` does nothing.

Comment: @Timo looks like you have a weird unicode character before `height` in this line `html, body { height: 100%; }`. Try copying and pasting my code, or using a plain text editor to edit your code.

Comment: @Timo no problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the 100% height to that section as well because it is a children of the body. And also if your intention is truly centralize the text as well then you have to give that height to that text div(containing the logo class) too because  it doesn't get that height automatically.

Additionally, I reset the margin and padding of the body to cover 100% of the viewport.

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

    .background-image {
      background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .logo {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

  <section class="background-image">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 class="title">site-title</h1>
      <h2 class="description">site-description</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  </body>  
</html>
```